# socket.recvfrom(1024) throws socket.error invalid argument supplied

Tags: python, sockets

I have started to learn UDP sockets but for some reason this code is throwing an error.  why does this code:

```
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
x=s.recvfrom(1024)
```

throw an error of invalid argument supplied?

Comment: Works for me, can you show the full error output and traceback?

Comment: Are you running on windows? Since you haven't bound a port, I'm not sure what should happen... on my linux machine I don't get an error but the call doesn't return either. On windows there may be an underlying permissions error.

Comment: @tdelaney yea im using windows.  How would i bind it to a port?

Comment: Here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python practice\udpclient.py", line 4, in <module>
print s.recvfrom(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Comment: `s.bind((hostname, portunumber))` where hostname is usually just an empty string but could be a local interface IPv4 address such as `192.168.0.1` and portnumber is the integer port you want.

Comment: @tdelaney how would I do that if i binded to the same hostname and portnumber in a server running on the same computer?

Comment: Only the side doing `recvfrom` should bind to the address. All clients should bind to a different port (or let sockets select a client port automatically) and do `s.sendto(data, (hostname, portnum))`. Its like any other service, only 1 can receive the data ... or everything would be jumbled. If you really do need multiple listeners you need multiple port numbers and some way of letting clients know what they are.

Comment: @tdelaney oh ok thanks! i guess that was my problem because i was trying to have every client connect to the same port like i did with TCP connections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UDP datagram communications take place between source and destination ports. You can assign a port with a `bind` call or let the network stack choose one for you by simply calling one of the send/recv methods. If you call `sendto` (and you have no bound a port), the stack will assign a number in the dynamic port range. If you call `recvfrom`, the stack will typically assign port 0. But there is no port 0. What happens next is platform dependent. Windows will attempt to bind you as a promiscuous listener. But that is a privileged call and you will likely get an invalid argument error. But it may work if you are administrator - i'm not sure.

To start a conversation, the first entity to send something needs to know what destination port to use. That means that the entity that receives the first communication needs to bind to a port number that the other side knows about in advance. This could be a well-known port number, a port hardwired into your code, something in a config file or even something advertised with a name service protocol such as LDAP.

Once that first datagram is received the receiving entity now has the senders address and port number so can talk back.

In your example, your entities could agree on a well-known port and begin a conversation. here is a datagram echoer listening on port 9999.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 9999))
while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(8096)
    s.sendto(data, addr)
```

and a client that talks to it

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for i in range(10):
    s.sendto(str(i), ('', 9999))
    print(s.recvfrom(1024))
```

Comment: Good insight into Windows behavior - never knew about it.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me resolved a really frustrating problem with a socket listener not working cross-platform.